# How do I display a calculation from table entries?

Tags: javascript, object

My code should calculate the vehicle’s fuel consumption by dividing the fuel tank volume by the distance traveled, then display the answer in the table row 'Fuel consumption'. Then, the 'Most efficient' column should display an asterisk in the row of the most efficient vehicle.

The homework says to use an object but I just don't understand how they work. Please help, I'm super stuck.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Registration Number</th>
        <th>Volume of fuel tank (litres)</th>
        <th>Distance traveled on full tank (km) </th>
        <th>Fuel consumption (litres/Km) </th>
        <th>Most efficient</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p id="registration1"></p></td>
        <td><p id="tank1"></p></td>
        <td><p id="distance1"></p></td>
        <td><p id="consumption1"></p></td>
        <td><p id="efficient1"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p id="registration2"></p></td>
        <td><p id="tank2"></p></td>
        <td><p id="distance2"></p></td>
        <td><p id="consumption2"></p></td>
        <td><p id="efficient2"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p id="registration3"></p></td>
        <td><p id="tank3"></p></td>
        <td><p id="distance3"></p></td>
        <td><p id="consumption3"></p></td>
        <td><p id="efficient3"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p id="registration4"></p></td>
        <td><p id="tank4"></p></td>
        <td><p id="distance4"></p></td>
        <td><p id="consumption4"></p></td>
        <td><p id="efficient4"></p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    
<script>

var i = 1;
var registration = [];
var tank = [];
var distance = [];
var consumption = [];

function Vehicle() {
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    registration.push(prompt("Please enter a 6-character vehicle registration number"));
    document.getElementById("registration" + i).innerHTML = registration[i - 1];
    
    tank.push(prompt("Please enter the volume of the vehicle's fuel tank in litres"));
    document.getElementById("tank" + i).innerHTML = tank[i - 1];
    
    distance.push(prompt("Please enter the distance the vehicle can travel on a full tank of fuel"));
    document.getElementById("distance" + i).innerHTML = distance[i - 1];
```

Comment: What have you tried? What you don't understand about how objects work? Read resources about it like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) or [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and if you still have doubts, ask about them, but don't ask about how to solve your homework straight away. StackOverflow is not the place for that

Answer (score 0):

We should be able to gather the data, create a vehicle *object* and then sort by fuel consumption.

We'll then display an asterix beside the row corresponding to the most efficient vehicle.

```js
function getVehicleInfo(vehicleId) {
    var vehicle = {};
    vehicle.id = vehicleId;
    vehicle.registration = prompt("Please enter a 6-character vehicle registration number");
    vehicle.tank = (parseFloat(prompt("Please enter the volume of the vehicle's fuel tank in litres")));
    vehicle.distance = (parseFloat(prompt("Please enter the distance the vehicle can travel on a full tank of fuel")));
    // Fuel consumption is fuel used per kilometre. (Check for divide by zero)
    vehicle.consumption = vehicle.distance ? (vehicle.tank / vehicle.distance): null;
    return vehicle;
}

function displayVehicleInfo(vehicle) {
    rowElement = document.createElement("tr");
    rowElement.setAttribute("id", vehicle.id);
    tableElement = document.getElementById("vehicle-table");
    vehicleHtml = `<td>${vehicle.registration}</td>`
    vehicleHtml += `<td>${vehicle.tank}</td>`
    vehicleHtml += `<td>${vehicle.distance}</td>`
    vehicleHtml += `<td>${vehicle.consumption ? vehicle.consumption.toFixed(2): 'Unknown'}</td>`;
    rowElement.innerHTML = vehicleHtml;
    tableElement.appendChild(rowElement);
    return vehicle;
}

function ShowVehicleData() {
    var vehicles = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        // Create a vehicle object from the user input.
        var vehicle = getVehicleInfo(i);
        displayVehicleInfo(vehicle);
        vehicles.push(vehicle);
    }
  
    // Find the most efficient by sorting by fuel consumption.
    vehicles.sort((vehicleA, vehicleB) => vehicleA.consumption - vehicleB.consumption);
    mostEfficientId = vehicles[0].id;
    document.getElementById(mostEfficientId).innerHTML += "<td>*</td>"
}

ShowVehicleData();
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cerulean/bootstrap.css"  crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<table id="vehicle-table" class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>Registration Number</th>
    <th>Volume of fuel tank (litres)</th>
    <th>Distance traveled on full tank (km) </th>
    <th>Fuel consumption (litres/Km) </th>
    <th>Most efficient</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can read more about javascript objects [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp)

```
var vehicles = [];
function Vehicle() {
    var lowestConsumption = Infinity;
    var efficient = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        var vehicle = {}; //initialize an empty object

        vehicle.registration = prompt("Please enter a 6-character vehicle registration number");
        document.getElementById("registration" + i).innerHTML = vehicle.registration;

        vehicle.tank = prompt("Please enter the volume of the vehicle's fuel tank in litres");
        document.getElementById("tank" + i).innerHTML = vehicle.tank;

        vehicle.distance = prompt("Please enter the distance the vehicle can travel on a full tank of fuel");
        document.getElementById("distance" + i).innerHTML = vehicle.distance;

        vehicle.consumption = Number(vihecle.tank) / Number(vehicle.distance); //Number(string) will change the string to a number!
        document.getElementById("consumption" + i).innerHTML = vehicle.consumption.toString();

        if (vehicle.consumption < lowestConsumption) {
            lowestConsumption = vihecle.consumption;
            efficient = i;
        }

        vehicles.push(vehicle);
    }

    document.getElementById("efficient" + efficient).innerHTML = "*";
}
```